# does charging the phone with other chargers affect mobile or battery?

Tags: charging

Actually I used Micromax charger instead of Xolo  charger. I have xolo era x phone. My phone gets switched off if I keep it idle for 4 min.  Why it is happening?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Please take a look at our [charging tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/charging/info) and especially check the "Chargers/Cables" section (as for the title of your question). Concerning the question body ("Why is this happening?"), I can't tell, sorry.

Comment: Don't go just by the specifics in question.  See the answer which is generic while dealing with  specific  case.  Since you didn't specify the charger details you can check for yourself  but  my guess is that charger is not the problem for you.  What could be causing it  if not charger is not easy to answer as Izzy also mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Your phone can be affected by the charger if the wattage and/or the voltage for the phone is not the same for charger. It could also be a hardware issue like: a battery, certain apps, bad part, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the charger affects the phone (battery). For example if you charge a smartphone with a charger made for a tablet (which requires more energy) the phone charges faster, but its battery will get damaged when you do it too often. On the other hand, when you use a charger that is too weak, it might isn't even recognized by the phone and charges very slowly, if it charges.